# Can't access variables from another class?

Tags: ios, class, variables, swift, reduce

So I have a class named `FoodListTable` of type `UITableViewController`
I also have a variable that finds the sum of elements in an array:

```
var calorieTotal: Float {
    return calorieNumberArray.reduce(0 as Float) { $0 + Float($1) }
}
```

I did some tests, and this variable is computing correctly. However, when I try to use it in another class I named `Menu`, it computes to 0.0. I tried doing this:

```
@IBAction func calculateButtonTappedMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
let foodListTableAccess = FoodListTable()
let dividend = foodListTableAccess.calorieTotal
```

But when I do this, `var calorieTotal` still computes to 0.0. How can I fix this? I am very new to programming, so please provide all the code I need to fix it. Also, if needed, here is all the code in both the classes:

```
class FoodListTable: UITableViewController {
var calorieNumberArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
var foods = [Food]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.foods = [Food(Name: "Small French Fries: 197 Cal."),Food(Name: "Cheeseburger: 359 Cal., One Patty"),Food(Name: "Cheese Pizza: 351 Cal., One Slice"),Food(Name: "Fried Chicken Breast: 320 Cal."),Food(Name: "Large Taco: 571 Cal."),Food(Name: "Hotdog: 315 Cal., With Ketchup"),Food(Name: "Tuna Sandwich: 287 Cal."),Food(Name: "1 Cup Vanilla Ice Cream: 290 Cal."),Food(Name: "1 1/2 Cup Vegetable Salad: 30 Cal.")]
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.foods.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    var food : Food
    food = foods[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel.text = food.Name
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    return cell
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        if cell.accessoryType == .None {

            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                calorieNumberArray[0] = 197
            }
            if indexPath.row == 1 {
                calorieNumberArray[1] = 359
            }
            if indexPath.row == 2 {
                calorieNumberArray[2] = 351
            }
            if indexPath.row == 3 {
                calorieNumberArray[3] = 320
            }
            if indexPath.row == 4 {
                calorieNumberArray[4] = 571
            }
            if indexPath.row == 5 {
                calorieNumberArray[5] = 315
            }
            if indexPath.row == 6 {
                calorieNumberArray[6] = 287
            }
            if indexPath.row == 7 {
                calorieNumberArray[7] = 290
            }
            if indexPath.row == 8 {
                calorieNumberArray[8] = 30
            }
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        } else {

            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                calorieNumberArray[0] = 0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 1 {
                calorieNumberArray[1] = 0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 2 {
                calorieNumberArray[2] = 0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 3 {
                calorieNumberArray[3] = 0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 4 {
                calorieNumberArray[4] = 0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 5 {
                calorieNumberArray[5] = 0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 6 {
                calorieNumberArray[6] = 0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 7 {
                calorieNumberArray[7] = 0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 8 {
                calorieNumberArray[8] = 0
            }
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
    }
    println(calorieNumberArray)
    println(calorieTotal)
}
var calorieTotal: Float {
    return calorieNumberArray.reduce(0 as Float) { $0 + Float($1) }
}
}
class Menu: Calculator {

@IBOutlet weak var yourWeightTextFieldMenu: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var exerciseListPickerViewMenu: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var calculateButtonMenu: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var calculatorContainerMenu: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var answer1LabelMenu: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    calculatorContainerMenu.hidden = false
    answer1LabelMenu.hidden = true
    yourWeightTextFieldMenu.delegate = self
    exerciseListPickerViewMenu.delegate = self
    exerciseListPickerViewMenu.dataSource = self
    calculateButtonMenu.enabled = false
    yourWeightTextFieldMenu.addTarget(self, action:"yourWeightEditingChanged:", forControlEvents:.EditingChanged);
}
override func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let text = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    if textField == yourWeightTextFieldMenu {
        yourWeightFilled = text.toInt() != nil
    }
    return true
}
override func textFieldShouldClear(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    calculateButtonMenu.enabled = false
    return true
}
@IBAction func yourWeightEditingDidEndMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
    yourWeightTextFieldMenu.resignFirstResponder()
    self.yourWeight = (self.yourWeightTextFieldMenu.text as NSString).floatValue
}
override func validateCalculateButton() {
    self.calculateButtonMenu.enabled = (self.yourWeightFilled)
}
@IBAction func yourWeightEditingChangedMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.validateCalculateButton()
}
@IBAction func calculateButtonTappedMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
    calculatorContainerMenu.hidden = true
    answer1LabelMenu.hidden = false
    let foodListTableAccess = FoodListTable()
    let divisor = (yourWeight * exerciseCurrentValue)
    let dividend = foodListTableAccess.calorieTotal
    let result = (round(dividend / divisor))
    answer1LabelMenu.text = "It will take you about \(result) minutes to burn off those menu choices by performing that exercise."
    println("divisor: \(divisor), dividend: \(dividend), result: \(result)")
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yeah... The problem is that you're creating a new instance of the class instead of getting the current instance. Are you using a UINavigationController?

Comment: "so please provide all the code I need to fix it." – nope.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for code.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Honestly, the solution seems like it will require approximately 3 lines of code. It's not that serious.

Comment: OP, how are you transitioning from `FoodListTable` to `Menu`?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I am using a UINavigationController for the `FoodListTable` and I am transitioning from FoodListTable to Menu using a Navigation Bar, if that's what you mean. Sorry if I am misinterpreting your question, I am just a newcomer to coding and I'd just like to learn some things.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Sorry for the request of the code, I will be more careful in the future. I just have to get his application done very soon, and I am very new to coding.

Comment: @TheCentral I've updated my answer to cover the case where your app isn't in fact UINavigationController based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new instance of the class instead of getting the current instance. If you're using in fact a `UINavigationController` and you transitioned to `Menu` immediately from `FoodListTable` as you've said in your comment, something like the following code should allow you to access the instance of `FoodListTable` currently on the navigation stack:

```
@IBAction func calculateButtonTappedMenu(sender: AnyObject) {

    let navigationController: UINavigationController = self.navigationController!
    let numberOfViewControllers = navigationController.viewControllers.count
    var foodListTableAccess: FoodListTable = navigationController.viewControllers[numberOfViewControllers - 2] as FoodListTable

    let dividend = foodListTableAccess.calorieTotal

}
```

Edit: If your code isn't in fact structured with a `UINavigationController` as you think, but you are in fact using storyboard as you mentioned in another comment, here's what you can do to pass your view controller object in from the previous class.

In the `FoodListTable` view controller, update `prepareToSegue` to share your current `FoodListTable` instance:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // (Uncomment the if block and specify a segue if this isn't the
    // segue leading from your view controller.)
    //if segue.identifier == "yourSegueName" {
    let menu = segue.destinationViewController as Calculator
    menu.foodListTable = self;
    //}
}
```

Then in your `Menu` view controller add a corresponding class variable to hold the `FoodListTable` object:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var foodListTable: FoodListTable!
```

That way you can access its values within `Menu` like so:

```
@IBAction func calculateButtonTappedMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
    let dividend = foodListTable.calorieTotal
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a pretty poor answer. You are assuming that `FoodListTable` is one level under `Menu`, and that poster is using a navigation controller. Neither of which is justified. Even if your assumptions are right, digging into the navigation controller's view stack to extract information is the worst possible solution to this problem. If the `Menu` object needs the data, then it should be passed into the object, the object shouldn't have to root around for it.

Comment: @DanielT. I'm not assuming anything. The OP said both of those things in a comment under his answer: "I am using a UINavigationController for the FoodListTable and I am transitioning from FoodListTable to Menu using a Navigation Bar, if that's what you mean. Sorry if I am misinterpreting your question, I am just a newcomer to coding and I'd just like to learn some things."

Comment: No problem, I think I have answered a question or two of yours in the past. A basic principle of OO programming is this... Give objects the data they need, don't force them to hunt around for it.

Comment: @DanielT. Of mine? Never.

Comment: Hmm... Well I've seen the name before. At any rate, your answer prompted me to add an extra paragraph to my answer to give more detail.

Comment: @DanielT. Although I agree with that passing info in is the best method, I like to try to answer questions so that they're as similar to OP's code as possible. The OP originally tried to access `foodListTableAccess.calorieTotal` so I showed him/her how he/she could achieve that. I'll stick by this answer for that reason.

Comment: I found it, you were helping me with a different newbie's Tick-tac-toe question. By all means, stand by your answer. If the OP actually has setup his code the way he says, your answer works. I'm just pointing out that there is a more appropriate way to do it.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Your new assumption of me not using the navigation controller actually worked! I just realized I didn't even use one to transition :)

Comment: @TheCentral Glad to hear :)

Answer (score -1):

I see where you say that you are new to programming. I think the program you are writing is a bit too complicated for your first attempt. You should probably spend more time playing around in a playground before tackling this task.

Now to the question at hand... Think about the `calorieNumberArray` for a bit, in what method is it filled with the necessary data? How is creating a new instance of `FoodListTable` going to cause that array to get filled? It isn't.

What you need to do is pass the information into your `Menu` object instead of trying to pull it out of your `FoodListTable`. How you do that depends on how the `Menu` object is created and what the relationship is between `FoodListTable` and `Menu`.

I suggest you remove the code you posted in your question and instead put in just enough code to show us how you create the `Menu` object and how you are giving it control. Then we can show you the best way to pass the data from `FoodListTable` to `Menu`.

If you are manually pushing the `Menu` onto the stack somewhere, then pass it the calorie information just after you create it. If you are using the storyboard and segues, then pass the information into the `Menu` in the `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: Yes, I see. Basically, the reason I separated the classes was because FoodListTable class is a subclass of UITableViewController while Menu is a subclass of ViewController, and I can't combine them because View Controller and UITableViewController already have many of the same properties.

Comment: And yes, I am using the storyboard and segues.